# "handshake error: Wrong response line" when connecting to websocket

Tags: node.js, perl, websocket

I'm trying to connect to a websocket with the following Perl code:

```
use AnyEvent;
use AnyEvent::WebSocket::Client 0.12;

my $client = AnyEvent::WebSocket::Client->new;

$client->connect("wss://example.com")->cb(sub {
    my $connection = eval { shift->recv };  # This line is generating the error
    if($@) {
        # handle error...
        warn $@;
        return;
    }

    # send a message through the websocket...
    $connection->send('');

    # receive message from the websocket...
    $connection->on(each_message => sub {
        my($connection, $message) = @_;
        print "Recieved Message...\n"
    });

    # handle a closed connection...
    $connection->on(finish => sub {
        # $connection is the same connection object
        my($connection) = @_;
        print "Disconnected...\n";
    });

$connection->close;

});
AnyEvent->condvar->recv;
```

However, I get the following error:

```
handshake error: Wrong response line at websocket.pl line 10.
```

How can I fix this error?

---

As an aside, what I'm trying to do is port the following working node.js code to Perl:

```javascript
var autobahn = require('autobahn');
var wsuri = "wss://example.com";
var connection = new autobahn.Connection({
    url: wsuri,
    realm: "realm1"
});

connection.onopen = function (session) {
    function txtEvent (args,kwargs) {
        console.log(args);
    };
    session.subscribe('textmsg', txtEvent);
}

connection.onclose = function () {
    console.log("Connection closed");
}

connection.open();
```

I'm also reviewing a [tutorial on Perl socket programming](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_socket_programming.htm).

Any help either debugging it or advice on which package I should use to connect (other than [`AnyEvent::WebSocket::Client`](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent::WebSocket::Client)) would be helpful.

Comment: AutobahnJS is an implementation of WAMP (over WebSocket). WAMP-over-WebSocket requires a client to announce "wamp.2.json" (or variants) as a WebSocket subprotocol in the opening handshake. When your client doesn't, a conforming WAMP server will deny the WebSocket connection. Maybe this is happening, and Perl spits out the unhelpful/incorrect "wrong response" error message.

Comment: Yep thats why, sadly i dont know how to fix it, ill read up on it later for now im just using the js.

Comment: I am getting a similar error: "Can't locate object method "recv" via package ..."

Answer (score 0):

The error messages looks like a SSL handshake problem.
(websocket uses wss).
Are the certificates trusted?
You might add this:

```
# Ignore SSL verification issues
$client->{ssl_no_verify} = 1;
```

I tested your code against my websocket and it works. (no error message).