# connecting to WebSocket giving "handshake error: wrong response line"

Tags: perl, websocket, handshake

I have created the following WebSocket client connection according to https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent::WebSocket::Client#SYNOPSIS:

```
use Data::Dumper;
use AnyEvent;
use AnyEvent::WebSocket::Client;

my $client = AnyEvent::WebSocket::Client->new;

$client->connect("wss://example:8080")->cb(sub {
    my $connection = eval { shift->recv };
    if($@) {
        warn $@;
        return;
    }
    $connection->send("My message");

    $connection->on(each_message => sub {
        my($connection, $message) = @_;
        print "Recieved Message: $message\n"
    });
    $connection->on(finish => sub {
        my($connection) = @_;
        print "Disconnected...\n";
    });
    $connection->close;
});

AnyEvent->condvar->recv;
```

It gives me "handshake error: wrong response line at" line my $connection = eval { shift->recv };

I tried solving the issue according to ["handshake error: Wrong response line" when connecting to websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487175/handshake-error-wrong-response-line-when-connecting-to-websocket) however it keeps giving me an issue.

Can you help me how to get around the handshake error and firmly establish the WebSocket connection?

Comment: Can you please also provide the server you are trying to reach?

Comment: @mat_luk -- Could be a port issue. Try changing the port in `connect` method.